# Calculate the mass of a solid which is bounded by...

Tags: calculus

Calculate the mass of the solid bounded below by the paraboloid

$z=x^2+2y^2$

and above by the parabolic cylinder

$z=8-x^2$

if the density $\lambda(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ varies with distance from z axis

I set up a triple integral using cylindrical coordinates, I found the paraboloid and cylinder intersect at a circle of radius $2$.

Upper and lower bounds of $z$ being $4$ and $8$, Integrating $\theta$ about the entire circle, so $0$ to $2\pi$. I found the mass to be $32\pi$

Ive tried to explain my process as quickly and concisely as I can, if Its too brief, let me know and Ill elaborate. How does it look?

Comment: Better it would be if you supplied an illustration or diagram of the solid.

Comment: what is $\lambda(x,y,z)$

Comment: I just edited the post, my apologies, I missed it.